# Angularjs controller required by directive can not be found in transclude content

Tags: angularjs, directive

Recently I use angular to develop a directive, there is an directive which like ng-repeat to generate some records, I used transclude to implement it. but it raise an error that "Controller 'aArea', required by directive 'bSpan', can't be found!".

**1. ModuleA code**

```
    var moduleA = angular.module("moduleA", []);

    moduleA.directive("aArea", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude:'element',
            scope: {
                amount:"="
            },
            template: '<div id=\"cc\" ng-transclude></div>',
            controller: function ($scope,$element,$attrs) {
                this.getData = function (data) {
                    return data + " is ok";
                }
            },
            compile: function (tElement, attrs, linker) {
                var parentElement = tElement.parent();

                return {
                    pre: function () {

                    },
                    post: function (scope) {
                        linker(scope.$parent,function (clone,scope) {
                            parentElement.append(clone);
                        });
                        linker(scope.$parent, function (clone, scope) {
                            parentElement.append(clone);
                        });
                        linker(scope.$parent, function (clone, scope) {
                            parentElement.append(clone);
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

   moduleA.directive("bSpan", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: "=",
            },
            template: '<span style=\"background-color:gray;color:orange\">{{data}}</span>',
            require: "^aArea",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, controller) {
                var data = "abc";
            }
        }
    });
```

**2. ModuleB COde**

```
    var moduleB = angular.module("moduleB", []);

    moduleB.directive("myItem", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                item: "=",
                itemTemplate: '='
            },
            priority: 1000,
            terminal:false,
            template: '<ng-include src=\"itemTemplate\"/>',
            controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var data = "";
            }
        }
    })
```

**3. ModuleC Code**

```
    var moduleC = angular.module("moduleC", ["moduleA", "moduleB"]);
    moduleC.controller("Ctr", function ($scope) {
        $scope.item = {};
        $scope.item.dataAmount = 1000;
        $scope.item.templateUrl = "item-template.html";
    })
```

**4. Html Code**

```
<body>
<div ng-app="moduleC">
    <div ng-controller="Ctr">
        <a-area>
            <my-item item="item" item-template="item.templateUrl"></my-item>
        </a-area>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**5. template code**

```
<div>
    <span style="display:block">hello every one</span>
    <b-span data="item.dataAmount"></b-span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the transclude function (that you called `linker`) of the `compile` function - it is deprecated.

From `$compile` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-compile-):

> Note: The `transclude` function that is passed to the compile function is deprecated, as it e.g. does not know about the right outer scope. Please use the transclude function that is passed to the link function instead.

Following this guidance (and a few other minor changes for the better), change the `aArea` directive as follows:

```
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
  // don't use the template element 
  //var parentElement = tElement.parent();

  return function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude) {
      transclude(function(clone, scope) {
        element.after(clone);
      });
      transclude(function(clone, scope) {
        element.after(clone);
      });
      transclude(function(clone, scope) {
        element.after(clone);
      });
  };
}
```

In fact, you don't even need the `transclude` function at all and you don't need to do `transclude: "element"`. You could just change to `transclude: true` and use `<div ng-transclude>` 3 times in the template.

Comment: Great, your suggestion makes sense in the application. but this just is a simple sample related to my actual application.  even though I use the transclude function in link function, it also can't find the required controller.so what is the reason that cause this type of issue?

Comment: @RonSmith, this should just work. I reproduced your example in a plunker and the fix suggested in the answer makes it work: http://plnkr.co/edit/VAIPIDfoQT41tYRiDAhL?p=preview

Comment: First of all I appreciate your answer, and the example indeed work well with the answer above. because it is more complex in my actual app, so I just imitate it to create this example. But with the answer the actual app still have this issue. so I want to know the potential reason,  I can  have direction to approach it.

Comment: @RonSmith It's difficult to say without spending hours knee deep in Angular's source. Somehow, the parent element `aArea` does not have a controller set in its data when you use a compile's transclude, triggering this error

Comment: Thanks your feedback however.  this issue confused me about two weeks. Although in the simple demo it can be solved, but in real application, there are two third  party directive that can't work together well, I just need to approach it, but I have no idea to find the reason and fix it. here is the ulr of the simple copy http://1drv.ms/1QyAFr9, I will appreciate if you help me review it.